Dependency management and execution environment in apache flink
we are evaluating apache flink for deploying streaming ml applications.
How is dependency management handled in apache flink and especially the execution environment?
Imagine python tasks with different dependencies should be submitted to the flink cluster.
We only see that flink Task Manager can handle dependency management with python virtual environments. When we have different dependencies for every task should we deploy a new task manager for every task?
Coming from a container setup, we could deploy every task inside a separate docker image.
How is this usually handled when using apache flink? We do not see that flink is great at handling a huge number of tasks that need their specific dependencies, but would like to make use of the streaming processor.

The solution is to use a more modern Python-native alternative:

Pathway (business source license, Python + Rust)
Bytewax (open source, Python + Rust)
Quix (available as open source, Python + C#)


Hey, thx for pointing me to those other solutions. Seems like a great fit

The pattern most often seen is to deploy the flink operator in kubernetes and then you run a task manager for every additional workload. The problem is that this is very resource intensive.

Thx for the answer. Do you know if this a production approach?
